# marketplace.magento.com extension install

Tags: extensions, composer, magento2.4.6, magento2marketplace, composer-install

I've been messing around with magento 2 for some time now and especially composer. find out what all the command lines are. downloading extensions and unpacking them in the right folder also works reasonably well. now there are a number of extensions that I would like to buy from, for example: https://marketplace.magento.com/ I just really can't figure out how to install this app with composer.

For example, I entered the following command:
composer require magevision/module-admin-category-product-thumbnail:v2.4.2

I need public key and private key, which I have created and filled in and entered the module name and version number. but just can't get it right. could someone explain me step by step how to install this?

I uninstalled Magento completely and reinstalled it for a fresh start. I can log in to my server with SSH and with filezilla I can access my files.

hopefully somebody can help me.

ps. i use magento 2.4.6

Sincerely,

joel

Answer (score 0):

You don't give an error message, so it's impossible to say where your problem is.

A few ideas:

1. you must purchase the extension in the marketplace before you can install it
2. the public and private keys have to be from your marketplace account  settings (the same account which you used to purchase the extension), not something you created on your own computer
3. if you still have problems, I'd omit the version "v2.4.2" and see what happens
4. add "-vvv" to the composer command for a more in-depth error message

Comment: first of all thanx for the fast answer!

correct, I did not add any error codes because I lost the overview for a while.

correct, I created the public key and private key within marketplace.magento.com.

actually I'm looking for a step-by-step plan for entering the command lines in the composer for installing from marketplace.magento.com.

And do I still have to edit files with filezilla. if so, which files should I modify.

sorry I've seen and read so many different ways that I don't remember how and what.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/tutorials/extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

To install the extension purchase from marketplace, you need to follow these steps.

1. Open the `magento root` into `CLI.`
2. Run extension installation command,

   composer require magevision/module-admin-category-product-thumbnail:2.4.2
3. Now it ask `username`, where you need to enter your `Public Key of marketpalce`.
4. Now it ask `password`, where you need to enter your `private key of marketplace`.
5. Then you can run the following commands one's.

   ```
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   php bin/magento cache:flush
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
   ```